# How to run a large amount of python code from a string?

Tags: python, url, python-3.x, exec, dropbox

I need to be able to run a large amount of python code from a string. Simply using `exec` doesn't seem to work, as, while the code runs perfectly in a normal setting, doing it this way seems to throw an error. I also don't think I can just import it as it it hosted on the internet. Here is the code:

```
import urllib.request

URL = "https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/127476718/instructions.txt"  

def main():
    instructions = urllib.request.urlopen(URL)

    exec(instructions.read().decode())

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

This is the error I've been getting:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Python33\rc.py", line 12, in <module>
    main()
  File "C:\Python33\rc.py", line 9, in main
    exec(instructions.read().decode())
  File "<string>", line 144, in <module>
  File "<string>", line 120, in main
NameError: global name 'Player' is not defined
```

The code I'm trying to run is available in the link in the first code snippet.

If you have any questions I'll answer them. Thank you.

Comment: You might want to give some thought to the security implications of this design.

Comment: On NPE's point, it may be useful to consider PyPy's [sandboxing](http://doc.pypy.org/en/latest/sandbox.html) feature.

Comment: Adding on to NPE's point, note this from the urllib docs: `When opening HTTPS URLs, it does not attempt to validate the server certificate. Use at your own risk!` In other words, man-in-the-middle attacks are possible, and this design would allow an attacker to execute arbitrary code on your system.

Comment: Is it still an issue given that the way I intend to use this is to write the code it links to myself, host it on dropbox and give this code out as an executable. (Thus making updating the code much easier).

Comment: That ought to work. What's the error you're getting?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Without specifying globals, the [`exec` function](http://hg.python.org/cpython/file/d9893d13c628/Python/bltinmodule.c#l805) (Python/bltinmodule.c) uses `PyEval_GetGlobals()` and `PyEval_GetLocals()`. For the execution frame of a function, the latter creates a new `f_locals` dict, which will be the target for the `IMPORT_NAME`, `STORE_NAME`, `LOAD_NAME` ops in the compiled code.

At the module level in Python the normal state of affairs is `globals() == locals()`. In that case `STORE_NAME` is using the module's globals, which is what a function defined within the module will use as its global namespace. However, using separate dicts for globals and locals obviously breaks that assumption.

The solution is to to manually supply `globals`, which `exec` will also use as `locals`:

```
def main():
    instructions = urllib.request.urlopen(URL)
    exec(instructions.read().decode(), globals())
```

You could also use a new dict that has `__name__` defined:

```
def main():
    instructions = urllib.request.urlopen(URL)
    g = {'__name__': '__main__'}
    exec(instructions.read().decode(), g)
```

I see in the source that the current directory will need a sound file named "pickup.wav", else you'll just get another error.

Of course, the comments about the security problems with using `exec` like this still apply. I'm only addressing the namespace technicality.

Answer (score 1):

First I thought you might try `__import__` with a StringIO object.  Might look something like [StackOverflow: Local Import Statements in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1699108/local-import-statements-in-python).

... but that's not right.

Then I thought of using the `imp` module but that doesn't seen to work either.

Then I looked at: Alex Martelli's answer to [Use of Eval in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1087255/use-of-eval-in-python) --- and tried to use it on a silly piece of code myself.

I can get the `ast` object, and the results of the `compile()` from that (though it also seems that one can simply call `compile(some_string_containing_python_source, 'SomeName', 'exec')` without going through the `ast.parse()` intermediary step if you like.  From what I gather you'd use `ast` if you wanted to then traverse the resulting syntax tree, inspecting and possibly modifying nodes, before you compiled it.

At the end it seems that you'll need to `exec()` the results of your `compile()` before you have resulting functions, classes or variables defined in your execution namespace.

Comment: `__import__` takes module name as argument. The question you link to uses `StringIO` as an example of a module to import.

Comment: Yep, I see that now; hoping to fix that soon (using the `imp` module).

Answer (score 0):

You can use `pipe` to put all strings into a child process of python and get output result from it.

Google `os.popen` or `subprocess.Popen`

Comment: This just seems to throw a different error `FileNotFoundError: [WinError 2] The system cannot find the file specified`

Comment: You don't have to put code strings into a file. you just need to start a python sub-process and write code strings to its pipe.stdin.