# How to initialise long-lived variables?

Tags: python

I'm starting my first major foray into Python coming from C# and Java. Pretty good so far, but one concept I cannot seem to get a handle on is how to initialise long-lived variables that will be used in many modules and packages?

In C#, I could have an `Environment` or `Config` class that is instantiated at app startup and passed around through dependency injection or another mechanism that could hold the values.

As a specific example, I am using SQLAlchemy to do my db inserts. I have created a module `db.py` that has the db code in that looks like:

```
engine = create_engine('dburl', echo=True)

conn = engine.connect()

metadata = MetaData()

table_mytable = Table('mypackage', metadata,
    Column('id', String, primary_key=True),
    Column('mystuff', String),

ins = table_mytable.insert()    

def insert():
    result = conn.execute(ins)
```

other code then imports my `db` module and makes use of the `insert` function to do the inserts.

What I am having trouble with is, everytime I import my db module for use, will the `engine`, `conn`, `metadata` and `table_my_table` variables be re-created so essentially for every import I am reconnecting to the `db` and re-defining all the meta data?

Is this the correct and expected thing? Or is there a better way to approach this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> What I am having trouble with is, everytime I import my db module for use, will the `engine`, `conn`, `metadata` and `table_my_table` variables be re-created so essentially for every import I am reconnecting to the `db` and re-defining all the meta data?

No. Python caches imports: A module which is once imported will not be imported again, but the imported module is reused.

You can validate this, by placing a `test.py` in some directory:

```
print("foo")
```

and start a python interpreter:

```
>>> import test
foo
>>> import test
```

You’ll notice that the code is only run once.

> Or is there a better way to approach this?

Thus, having module-global variables is a valid way to keep state which needs to be kept for the whole program run.

Comment: Thanks Jonas, that really cleared a lot of things up for me. Also enabled me to find this SO question that has a good answer on how import actually works: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1699108/local-import-statements-in-python