# importing custom built libraries in python in windows environment

Tags: python

I have created the following files under the package name Operation.

```
# C:\Python27\Operation\addExample.py
def add(a, b):
   result = a + b
   return result

# C:\Python27\Operation\SubExample.py
def sub(a, b):
   result = a - b
   return result

# C:\Python27\Operation\__init__.py (an empty file)
# C:\Python27\Operation\test.py

from  Operation import addExample,SubExample

print(addExample.add(4,5))
print(SubExample.sub(4,5))
```

When I run the test.py , I get the following error. Can some one tell me how to fix the problem.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Python27\Operation\test.py", line 1, in <module>
    from  Operation import addExample,SubExample
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'Operation'
```

Comment: `C:\Python27\Operation__init__.py (an empty file)` is this line correct? or did you miss a `\ `?

Comment: You cannot import `Operation` from its root directory without introducing it to `sys.path`. You may use local import though. Check out possible duplicate question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1699108/local-import-statements-in-python

Comment: Did you *install* the `Operation` module? (In other words, is it on your $PYTHONPATH?) It won't magically become importable just because it exists.

Comment: No.It's just typo error.

Comment: Sorry, this link is more helpful: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4383571/importing-files-from-different-folder

Comment: "it on your $PYTHONPATH?) It won't magically become importable just because it exists.

Comment: "is it on your $PYTHONPATH?) It won't magically become importable just because it exists. "  - Iam a novice to Python programming.Please let me know the process to include in the $PYTHONPATH.