# Is it possible to import a Python module exclusively for its effect?

Tags: python

Essentially, I'm wondering if it's possible to do something like `from .my_script import None` in my package's `__init__.py` to execute `my_script.py` without introducing undesired variables into the namespace. I know you can do `from . import my_script; del my_script` - I thought it was possible there was a shortcut for this.

Comment: No shortcut, because it's not a common use-case for importing a module.

Comment: Would kind of be nice. Scapy makes extensive use of this. You need to import a module for the packet types to be "registered" so they're automatically parsed. But ya, this isn't very common, so it's not surprising that there isn't a shortcut.

Comment: If the module is designed to be used like this, it could delete all the names it defines at the end.

Answer (score 0):

Consider [Local import statements](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1716375/2550406).

You could do the `import foo` inside a function, which means it will not clutter the global namespace. However, there is an option that does not require a function def:

> `import foo` is roughly equivalent to this statement:
>
> ```
> foo = __import__('foo', globals(), locals(), [], -1)
> ```
>
> That is, it
> creates a variable in the current scope with the same name as the
> requested module, and assigns it the result of calling `__import__()`
> with that module name and a boatload of default arguments.

However, specifying that `-1` there seems to no longer be supported in python3. According to the [docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html?highlight=__import__#__import__), the level indicates

> `0` means only perform absolute imports. Positive values for level indicate the number of parent directories to search relative to the directory of the module calling `__import__()`.

So we will have to go with `0`... or if it needs to search in a parent directory, a corresponding positive number.

---

As an example, I have two files in the same folder.

##### foo.py

```py
print("Foo loaded")
```

##### bar.py

```py
print("Hello")
__import__('foo', globals(), locals(), [], 0)
print("World")
```

##### output

```
> python bar.py
Hello
Foo loaded
World
```

---

If you want this to be a shortcut because you do this often, you could define your own, easier to use, function that takes the module name and internally just does this.

Comment: `importlib` module would probably be better than a magic method

Comment: @OneCricketeer I'm not sure why (or why not), so.. feel free to write an answer as well if you'd like to elaborate :)